# Slice array by tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 by 20 array (A) that contains value rows and columns for another 2d array (B).

The 2x20 array looks like this:

```
A =  [[151 111]
     [184 150]
     [176 156]
     [101 224]
     [ 46 156]
     [134 152]
     [164 104]
     [110 252]
     [286 316]
     [320  56]
     [320  41]
     [164 173]
     [315 309]
     [356 231]
     [342 250]
     [183 332]
     [323 307]
     [298 239]
     [277 247]
     [223 228]]
```

, where the first column in the row, and the second is the column

What I want is to print values in B, for each combination of row/column from A.
I know how to print the values:

```
print B[151, 111]
print B[184, 150]
```

But how can I do this automatically for each row/col combination in A?

Edit: Upon asking for the full code, I posted it below.

```
c1 = np.array([148, 108])
c2 = np.array([181, 147])
c3 = np.array([173, 153])
c4 = np.array([98, 221])
c5 = np.array([43, 153])
c6 = np.array([131, 149])
c7 = np.array([161, 101])
c8 = np.array([107, 249])
c9 = np.array([283, 313])
c10 = np.array([317, 53])
c11 = np.array([317, 38])
c12 = np.array([161, 170])
c13 = np.array([312, 306])
c14 = np.array([353, 228])
c15 = np.array([339, 247])
c16 = np.array([180, 329])
c17 = np.array([320, 304])
c18 = np.array([295, 236])
c19 = np.array([274, 244])
c20 = np.array([220, 225])

trees_list = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19, c20]

def tree_add_rcol(filt_size, tree):
    rc_add = filt_size // 2
    tree_add = tree + rc_add
    print tree_add
    return tree_add


def trees_pixel(rc_list, site):
    t_row = rc_list[0]
    t_col = rc_list[1]
    tree = site[t_row, t_col]
    print tree
    return tree

for i in trees_list:
    trees_pixel(i, site)

def trees_add_matrix(trees_list):
    list = []
    for i in trees_list:
        tree = tree_add_rcol(7, i)
        list.append(tree)
    trees_mat = np.array(list)
    print trees_mat
    return trees_mat

A = trees_add_matrix(trees_list)
B = np.genfromtxt('E:.....\Input\Plot_1.txt', dtype=None, delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: In your given example, `print A[151, 111]` would raise an error since A is a 20-value list...

Comment: I changed, saw it now.

Comment: Makes more sense now! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well ... you don't... in lists you use `B[151][111]`

Comment: I tried iterating for each row and column in A, but it doesn't print how it should. Ex: 'for i in A[0]:
    for j in A[1]:
        print B[i,j]'

Comment: The code is very long, but I summarised the problem with the main post. I can post it, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, you said it doesn't work and you want help with it.

Comment: First. It is not A[123, 456]. It is A[123][456]. That said, to get value of B for coordinates stored in A[10] you would go B[A[10][0]][A[10][1]]. Ugly. I know.

Comment: I now got a bit mad/angry... Now we can see that your talking about NUMPY ARRAYS and not LISTS ...

Comment: Apparently the original question was unclear about the use of `numpy` - except that the print of `A` is numpy like, not nest lists (note the missing commas).  The added code makes it clear this is `numpy`.  I edited the tags accordingly.  For numpy `B[i,j]` is the correct 2d indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
for i,j in A:
   print( B[i][j] )
```

Comment: @Litwos Wasn't that same thing written in the comments above?